# how to get started with the oauth2-playground

Tags: oauth2-playground

My fitbit account was recently moved to google. I would like to be able to access my own data there from a desktop app.  Will the Google Fitness API V1 allow me to do this? Where can I find documentation to help me with this?  I've tried using the oauth2-playground but only get responses of not authorized.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow  Please read: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/4800344). I also recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).